# can i detect a long press in service

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to use a service to detect a long press event. and when user have a long press in screen, I get the long press coordinate. I have trying to use SimpleOnGestureListener but I'm failed. Does anybody can tell me how to detect a long press in service. thanks!!

Comment: What are you trying to do? I doubt that you can directly grab user input on other apps, as that would be terrible in terms of security.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in a Service? Can't you just do it in your Activity instead and then launch a service from there? Or couldn't you just use a Broadcast Receiver? By definition, a background non-ui Service really has nothing to do with user input in the ui.

Answer (score 0):

GestureDetector.OnGestureListener is your friend

[Interface / GestureDetector.OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html)

By the way I think you should do it into an Activity.